# Android LazyAdapter - displaying same data on two TextViews and an ImageView

Tags: android, listview

In my ListView there are 2 TextViews and an ImageView. 
I am using a LazyAdapter to load images from JSON file according to [this link](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/).

I am successfully loading data but i am facing the problem that each list item shows in both TextViews the link of the image while the image itself is shown correctly.

Here is the adapter: 
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

```
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView price = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.price); 
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); 

    HashMap<String, String> smart = new HashMap<String, String>();
    smart = data.get(position);

    id.setText(smart.get(SmActivity.KEY_ID));
    name.setText(smart.get(SmActivity.KEY_NAME));

    price.setText(smart.get(SmActivity.KEY_PRICE));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(smart.get(SmActivity.KEY_THUMB), image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

And here is the activity:  
public class SmActivity extends ListActivity {

```
static String url = "url-php to get json";

public static String KEY_PRICE, KEY_NAME, KEY_THUMB;

ListView list;  
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> smList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJson(url);

    try {
        JSONArray smJArray = json.getJSONArray("sm");
        for(int i = 0; i < smJArray.length(); i++){

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject jsonObj = smJArray.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put(KEY_NAME, jsonObj.getString("product_name"));
            map.put(KEY_PRICE, jsonObj.getString("price")+"€");
            map.put(KEY_THUMB, jsonObj.getString("image_main"));
            smList.add(map);       
        }   
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    list = (ListView)getListView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, smList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

I can understand that ListView shows at all items the value of the last `map.put(...)` i am using. 
For example, if the last put in HashMap is map.put(KEY_PRICE, jsonObj.getString("price")+"€");  
i get the price value not only on price, but on name TextView as well. And of course i get no image.

I would be grateful in any help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend verifying the data that gets put into your hashmap (through logging), and then checking it again as you pull it out.  Once you can prove the data that's actually in the map you're getting, we'll be able to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your respone @Jon O. I am not familiar with logs so i am not pretty sure if i used it correctly. But i tested a `Log.d(KEY_THUMB, "testing ...");` without showing any log error. No either by using the other keys and smList.toString().

Comment: I'm not sure if this help, but in .xml file when i am using `android:id="@+id/list"` and in activity `list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);` the app terminates unexpectedly.   When i am using `android:id="@android:id/list"` and `(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);` behaves like i wrote before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. i got it. i replaced:

`public static String KEY_PRICE, KEY_NAME, KEY_THUMB;`

by

`static final String KEY_NAME = "product_name";`
`static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";`

and

`map.put("product_name", jsonObj.getString(KEY_NAME));`
`map.put("price", jsonObj.getString(KEY_PRICE));`